# Issue opening a websocket connection using websocket-client Python

Tags: python, macos, websocket

When I run this script on my PC, the websocket connection is established properly and the messages are printed to the terminal as they should.

Now, I cloned my project to my mac and when I try to run the code nothing happens. The connection doesn't even open. I'm not getting any error messages either.

The websocket module has been installed successfully `pip install websocket-client`

Is there something that I am missing? I can't find the issue.

Cheers,

```
import json
import websocket

socket = 'wss://ws-feed.exchange.coinbase.com'

def on_open(ws):
    print("opened")
    subscribe_message = {
    "type": "subscribe",
    "channels": [{ "name": "ticker", "product_ids": ["BTC-USD"] }]
}

    ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe_message))

def on_message(ws, message):
    print("received a message")
    print(json.loads(message))

def on_close(ws):
    print("closed connection")

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_close=on_close)

ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: Im currently facing the same issue. Any update on that? In my case, the mac-os python interpreter doesnt recognize the websocket-client library